# Created time column with default Now() value using code first entity models

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

The postgres function Now() can be used to set a created time for any row. It is defined as this using postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
    stud_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    stud_name Text NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT Now()
);
```

The problem is. I am using the code first approach with entity models. How can I then achieve the same functionality without adding a lot of extra code?

My class look like:

```
public class student
{
    public int stud_id { get; set; }
    public string stud_name { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/31025967/code-first-migration--how-to-set-default-value-for-new-property-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HasDefaultValueSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#default-values) should work fine and I think it is not a lot of extra code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<student>()
        .Property(b => b.created_date)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("NOW()");
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for :)
By the way, this goes into the context object.